# Get data of specific cell in HTML Table using Selenium Webdriver with Python

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My question aim: **To get the Name of the candidate (which is a part of a HTML Table) and write it into a file.**

*(my entire program, in point 2, aims at: Typing a register number in a website, hitting submit, getting the name of the candidate (which is the problem), putting the registration number with name in a file, then going back and repeating the same till the last number.)*
The table looks as follows: [HTML TABLE IN THE SITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUDKA.png)

1. The HTML Code, only for the table is as follows:

```html
<table  id="details" class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="15%">Name</td>
<td width="85%" colspan="3"><span style="font-weight: bold"> ANILKUMAR                     </span></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Reg. No.</td>
<td colspan="3"><span style="font-weight: bold"> 461684</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

2.My **PYTHON** code , as specified according to the aim,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui,pyperclip

#Function.
def fun1(roll_no):
    while(i<999999):

        #INPUT: Put's the number in text bar, in Home Page, then clicks "Submit"

        inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("reg")    
        inputElement.send_keys(roll_no)
        inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        #SNIPPET TO GET THE NAME OF CANDIDATE, HOW?

        #fs.write(str(i)+'\t'+name+'\n')  , to WRITE INTO FILE.
        #'name' in above line refers to the candidate's name, a string. 

        #OUT: Click's the "Back" button to go back to Home Page.

        outputElement = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Back')
        outputElement.click()
        roll_no = roll_no + 1



#MAIN MODULE

#OPENS Firefox using selenium webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

#The intended "Home Page"
browser.get("http://karresults.nic.in/indexpuc_2016.asp")

roll_no=110000  #Starting Roll Number.

#File open for writing.
fs=open("testfile.txt","w")
#call the function
fun1(i)
```

3. The Name of the candidate is always at row=0,col=1. 
   All I need is to access the cell having the name, using selenium. I don't need to loop through all the cells. 
   Please help me, I'm pretty new to Python and Selenium Webdriver Utility. Also, I've a link included of the picture above(I can't post pictures directly, as I've new, this is my first question and thus no reputation).
   Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
   Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a find_elements_by_xpath() to find all siblings of an element containing the text Name using the following xpath:

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("td[text()='Name']/following-sibling::td/span")
for element in list:
    print element.text
```

Comment: Thank you for the help sir! I was having problems with the xpath part. I've modified the snippet a bit and its working as needed.